# array concatenation of two different arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

im doing simple genetic algorithm  uniform crossover operation . for that im using two arrays as parent and mother.i want concatenate the childs for getting the offsprings(childs).
i have problem in adding the arrays .any help plssss.i did it ubuntu

```
#include<iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <algorithm>

#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int P[ ]={3,7,6,5,2,4,1,8};

    int N[ ]={8,6,7,2,5,3,4,1};

    int r= (sizeof(P)/sizeof(*P)) ;

    int s= (sizeof(N)/sizeof(*N));

    int val=r/2 ;

    int t1[val],t2[val],t3[val],t4[val],n=0,p=0;

    for(int m=0;m< val;m++)
    {

        t1[n]=P[m];

        t2[n]=N[m];

        n++;

    }

    for(int x=val;x< r;x++)
    {

        t3[p]=P[x];

        t4[p]=N[x];

        n++;
    }

    int* child=new int [val+val];

    copy(t1,t1+val,child);

    copy(t3,t3+val,child+val);

    cout << child;

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: you could spare yourself a lot of trouble by using std::vector instead

Comment: In C++ use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Comment: do u mean p++ in second for loop?
And when did you use variable`s` after you assign it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! **1.** why `<fstream>` and `<vector>` if you don't use it? **2.** Why C++ if you (almost) don't use its library? All that C-style array fiddling can be handled easily with C++ containers, **3.** Is there a question?/What is the question? **4.** Readability matters. Your all-lower-no-punctuation style is likely to turn people away who could help. **5.** "any help plssss.i did it ubuntu" - you want people to take your question *seriously*? **Please** read the FAQ and the ever-famous [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#intro)

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
int t1[val], t2[val], t3[val], t4[val]
```

You can only use constant values to declare the size of arrays.

You can either use a `std::vector` or dynamically allocate memory for the `t`-arrays.

```
std::vector<int> t1(val);
std::vector<int> t2(val);

for(int m = 0; m < val; m++)
{
   t1[n] = P[m];
   t2[n] = N[m];
   n++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple errors in your code.

1. Variable length arrays are at present not supported in C++.

   int val=r/2 ;
   int t1[val]; // Not OK
2. In the second for loop I guess you meant p++ instead of n++;
3. Instead of manually doing all the memory allocation - deallocation, you should use `std::vectors`
4. cout << child; // This outputs the address of the pointer, not the entire array.